# DEBIAN or debian in .deb package?

Tags: packaging

I am experimenting with creating a .deb package and am unsure about the file structure of a package. Is the directory that contains `control`, `changelog`, `rules`, etc supposed to be named `DEBIAN` or `debian`?

I am using `dpkg-deb` to package it, and it seems to require `DEBIAN`, and I am trying to use Lintian to check it, and it isn't recognizing the `changelog` or `copyright` files. Lintian throws the errors `debian-changelog-file-missing` and `no-copyright-file` but later warns `unknown-control-file changelog` and `unknown-control-file copyright`. Looking at [this page](https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/debian-dir-overview.html), it suggests using `debian`, and I rename the directory to that but it causes `dpkg-deb` to fail. Reading through the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/index.html), it usually uses `debian` in examples, but occasionally uses `DEBIAN`, which makes me wonder if in certain circumstances both may be needed. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When creating the package, you have a `debian` directory, which contains the data needed for making the package (the `control` file, the `rules`, the `changelog`, etc.). `dpkg-deb` is *not* the usual way to make a package - it just offers a quick way to assemble one. You usually use`dpkg-buildpackage` instead.

Answer (score 4):

**Source** packages (i.e. the not-yet-compiled source tree) use a lowercase `debian` directory. For example, if you were using `dpkg-buildpackage` to compile a C program and generate the binary .deb, you would have a source tree like this:

```
foo-1.0/
 ├─debian/
 │  ├─changelog
 │  └─control
 ├─main.c
 ├─main.h
 └─Makefile
```

The uppercase `DEBIAN` is apparently found only in **binary** packages (i.e. the compiled .deb files themselves), within their 'control.tar' archive.

However, according to the dpkg documentation, this 'DEBIAN' directory **is a historical leftover** from *very* old dpkg package formats (as in pre-2000s; see `man deb-old` and `man deb`). All new .deb packages instead put the control files directly at the top level of the 'control.tar' archive:

```
$ tar -tf control.tar
./changelog
./control
./postinst
```